# How to remember user form inputs in meteor?

Tags: meteor

Even if the user close the tab or refresh the tab or close the whole browser, next time he reopen the page, all inputs he made earlier in the form still exists.

Should I use `Session` or `new Collection('')` or `new Collection('temp_input')` or what?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a server collection, as either `Session` or local collections in meteor do not persist data after closing the browser / closing the app.

If you insist on keeping data on client-side, you can also have a look at those meteor projects:

- [GroundDB](https://github.com/GroundMeteor/db)
- [meteor-persistent-minimongo](https://github.com/frozeman/meteor-persistent-minimongo) (quite young)
- [meteor-offline-data](https://github.com/awwx/meteor-offline-data) (put on indefinite hold)

Comment: Neither actually... only for the duration of the app. A simple refresh would erase it.

Comment: Edited my answer with suggestions.